# Performance between trigger and ordinary update query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am in great confusion about the performance between trigger and ordinary update query.
In my site i am running cron operation in which it consists of 2 tables
    1. Cron log table
    2. Metadata table
My crons runs every minute. There are 2 ways(I think) to update  both the table,

1. I am fetching the datas from the Cron log table and calling the wistia api to upload the files. 
   After getting the response from the wistia I can update the status  in both the tables via Code.
2. I am fetching the datas from the Cron log table and calling the wistia api to upload the files. 
   After getting the response from the wistia I can update the status in "Cron" table via code and I can use the trigger to update the
   "Metadata" table after cron table update.

I don't know whether is it right to hit the Metadata table regualarly when the site is fetching datas from there.
In 2nd step I am in confusion that trigger may take time to fetch data and update the Metadata table.
Trigger also has no control over there.
Please suggest me the some steps with High performance. Which is better Trigger or Update ?

Comment: Well, you could try running the different methods and measure how long they take?

Comment: I dont hink a trigger is more performant as it still has to execute the orginary UPDATE, its just connected to an EVENT listener.This is especially saving trouble when the database is shared by more then one application, you do not have to code anything for the event to happen and you can be sure it cannot be forgotten somewhere. Stored procedures however are alot more performant then raw queries as they can be cached and stored preprocessed by the server. You can use a stored-procedure in the query executing your UPDATE this might bring both performance and comfort!